# Error in using "addpointcloud" in pcl

Tags: point-cloud-library

Here is my code for representing point cloud data.

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("arg[1]", *cloud) == -1)
return (-1);
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> (cloud, "sample cloud");
```

Does any one know why I can not see my point cloud data in the output.
While when I use the code below for showing above point cloud I can see it completely :

```
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer1 ("Simple Cloud Viewer");
viewer1.showCloud (cloud);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php#pcl-visualizer
Then you can see a code snippet like this function:

`boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> rgbVis`

I hope this will help you.